# reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop empty rows of 'price' column and reset them after.
But both `df = reset_index(drop=True)` and `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` didn't work for me. Does anyone know why?

```
# Before drop rows
print (df.shape)
print(df['price'].isnull().sum())
```

(205, 26)
4

```
df.dropna(subset=["price"], axis=0, inplace=True)

# After drop rows
print (df.shape)
print(df['price'].isnull().sum())
```

(201, 26)
0

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 
# After reset

print (df.shape)
print(df['price'].isnull().sum())
```

(201, 26)
0

Comment: The problem is not clear. You sum an array of scalar booleans returned by `isnull` method and obtain 0. It means the array contains only 0-s. 0 is false. So, your 0 represents the absence of null values. Your goal is acheived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really helps if you provide an example

1. to clarify your question
2. for us to try solutions.

You could try

```
old_index = df.index
df.dropna(subset=["price"], axis=0, inplace=True)
df.reindex(old_index)
```

`dropna` discards the index along with the values and therefore there are no old indices left, which could be reset with `reset_index()`

Comment: Not understand, first remove missing rows by `price` column and then add missing rows by `reindex` ? Do you test your solution? I think it is wrong.